# Decode with Wildcard character

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I'm trying to decode a column that contains names like `1.01 channel 1` and `2.04 channel 2`

To do this i first used Decode based on only the first number. However now I need to further split channel 2 down.

I tried to use this:

```
Decode(Substr(ch.sales_chain_desc,1,4), '1*', 'Channel 1', '2.01', 'Channel 2 a', '2.10', 'Channel 2 b', '2.02', 'Channel 2 c', 'Other')
```

However it gave the wrong result. Is there any other character i should use instead of * (asterix)

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work in the decode statement. As you see from the answer bellow it worked in the case statement. But thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's probably better to use [case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm) in this... case:

```
CASE 
  WHEN ch.sales_chain_desc LIKE '1%' THEN 'Channel 1'
  WHEN ch.sales_chain_desc = '2.01' THEN 'Channel 2 a'
  WHEN ch.sales_chain_desc = '2.10' THEN 'Channel 2 b'
  WHEN ch.sales_chain_desc = '2.02' THEN 'Channel 2 c'
  ELSE 'Other'
END
```

Comment: How do i use this case statement in a group by?

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm Do you want to group by the result of the case?

Comment: Then you'll need to use a subquery. SELECT * FROM (SELECT CASE...END As CaseValue) GROUP BY CaseValue